htaccess открывать содержимое страницы по другому адресу
Задача состоит в том что бы по адресу /proizvoditel/bmc/ отображалась страница /bmc/
Как сделать это перенаправление ?
Пробовал такие конструкции RewriteRule ^/proizvoditel/bmc/    /bmc/ [QSA,L]
Но пишет что такого адреса не существует.

Вот так:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^proizvoditel/bmc/$ /bmc/? [R=301,L]

Запрашиваем https://www.example.com/proizvoditel/bmc/, перенаправялем на https://www.example.com/bmc/
Можете также проверить, что правило работает.
Дополняю ответ, так как автору требовался (как оказалось) т.н. internal rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^proizvoditel/bmc/$ /bmc/? [L]

Проверить

Да перенапровление происход, но и сам юрл меняется на /bmc/. А мне нужно что бы юрл остался https://www.example.com/proizvoditel/bmc/ таким. Как это сделать ?

Очевидно, что в вопросе не стоило бы тогда использовать слово "перенаправление". Обновил ответ - добавил правило для internal rewrite
